# Web data scraper without httpwebrequest in .net

Tags: c#, .net

In .net there are some .net classes which uses IE component.By them we can read htmldom and do login and data scraping.
Kindly can any body give me the name of those classes /assemblies where it is present.I myself used it to login and data scrapping quite a way back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to it richard's.Just minor thing about HTMLTableRowCollection is left from HTMLTable.
My code is like following

```
        object o = null;
        InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorerClass();
        IWebBrowserApp wb = ie;
        wb.Visible = chkShowBrowser.Checked;
        wb.Navigate("http://LoginPage.aspx", ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);

        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        } while (wb.Busy);

        if (ie.Document != null)
        {
            var myDoc = ie.Document as HTMLDocument;

            if (myDoc != null)
            {
                var oUserName = (HTMLInputTextElement)myDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainBodyPlaceholder_PublicPortalLogin_UserName");
                oUserName.value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("userName");

                var oPassword =
                    (HTMLInputTextElement)
                    myDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainBodyPlaceholder_PublicPortalLogin_Password");
                oPassword.value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");

                var btnSubmitLogin =
                    (HTMLInputElement)myDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainBodyPlaceholder_PublicPortalLogin_Login");
                btnSubmitLogin.click();

                do
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                } while (wb.Busy);


                if (ie.Document != null)
                {
                    wb.Navigate("http://SearchPage.aspx", ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);


                    do
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    } while (wb.Busy);



                    if (ie.Document != null)
                    {

                        var oIncidentNumber =
                            (HTMLInputTextElement)
                            myDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainBodyPlaceholder_txtIncidentNumber");
                        oIncidentNumber.value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("incidentNumber");

                        var btnTicketNumberSearch =
                            (HTMLInputElement)myDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainBodyPlaceholder_btnSearch");
                        btnTicketNumberSearch.click();

                        do
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        } while (wb.Busy);

                        HTMLTable searchResultTable = myDoc.getElementById("ctl00_MainBodyPlaceholder_gdView_DXMainTable") as HTMLTable;



                        if (searchResultTable != null)
                        {
                            //foreach (var VARIABLE in searchResultTable.T)
                            //{

                            //}
                        }

                        if (chkRenderBody.Checked)
                        {
                            txtFinalTextBox.Text = myDoc.body.outerHTML;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How Can i close the question with accepting one comment as answer in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrape data from existing web pages, consider the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I were looking for mshtml and SHDocvw solution. your post helped in reminding about it.What I need a mshtml/sHdocvw solution where simply i can put data in certain login field then invoke some click event of a button.Then in the fresh page i have to read the htmldom.